# jquery getday() is giving me the wrong day?

Tags: jquery

I have a datepicker drop down

```
<input type="date" class="date">
```

I get the day of the week using jquery

```
function dateFunction() {
    $(".date").on('change', function () {
        var d = $('.date').val();
        var dm = new Date(d);
        var n = dm.getDay();
        alert(n);

    });
}
```

when I pick Tuesday the alert is 1?

Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: When I run that code here I do get `2`. Your time zone may be screwing you up - what do you get if you paste `new Date("7/12/2016").getDay()` into the browser console?

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/y174nvdv/

Comment: But in other places of the code like here: var today = new Date()
    var dayIndex = today.getDay()
     if (dayIndex == 2) {
        $(".tuesday").show();
        $(".daySelector").val('tuesday');
    } it gives me the right day?

Comment: `new Date()` may be assuming the date is in UTC, whereas `.getDay()` returns based on your local timezone. When using `type="date"`, the `.value` is usually given in an ISO-like format, which is parsed with the UTC assumption.

Comment: so how do I get around that?

Comment: @N.Sch Don't depend on the engine's choices with parsing. Parse it yourself or with a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) – [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object if expected result is `2` for Tuesday, use `Date.prototype.toUTCString()`, `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
var days = {
  Sun: 0,
  Mon: 1,
  Tue: 2,
  Wed: 3,
  Thu: 4,
  Fri: 5,
  Sat: 6
};

function dateFunction() {
  $(".date").on("change", function() {
    var day = days[this.valueAsDate.toUTCString().slice(0,3)];
    alert(day);
  });
}

dateFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date">
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! It just feels like there should be an easier way?

Comment: @N.Sch What do you mean by "easier"? Approach utilizes one object, one call to `.toUTCString()`, one call to `.slice(0,3)` to return expected result.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

> The value returned by getDay() is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Syntax can be used as `new Date(dateString);`

> **dateString**
>   String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).
>   Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

This being said, it is (1) to be expected that Tuesday is represented by the number 2, and (2) disencouraged to use new `Date(dateString)`. A better option would be parsing the date input's value into year/month/day and using the `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);` syntax.